# Add a new column to Pandas data frame with aggregated data

Tags: python, pandas

I implemented my own K-Fold cross validation (had a special case to deal with), and I need to save the predictions and its confidence as new columns.

1- In each iteration: `test_predictions = clf.predict(X_test)`

2- Compare the perditions to ground truth:

```
treatments = test_fold.loc[:, 'treatment'].unique().tolist()
idx = df.index[df['treatment'].isin(treatments)].tolist()
```

and Tried saving these values into a new column, but I have values for only one test fold and NOT the entire data set at each iteration, so it didn't work:

```
df.iloc[idx]['new_col'] = (y_test == test_predictions)
```

where y_test is the label data for the fold that was picked for testing (comparing the real labeled data with the classifier predictions)

How to aggregate all the predictions corresponding to the correct indexes of each test fold from each iteration, then save it as a new column on the origin data frame at the end (or during each iteration save one part each time)?

Comment: it's unclear what is `y_label` and `y_test`, need to add more info/context

Comment: y_test... is the label data for the fold that was picked for testing

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result. In this case, provide a few rows for each of `treatments`, `df`, and `y_test`, along with the corresponding expected result. Chances are the answer is super simple and fast (no Python loops) if we know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array with the results of the check at each iteration:

```
results = [y_test[i] == test_predictions[i] for i in range(len(y_test))]
```

After that, you need to select treatment objects by index and write the result via loc:

```
df.loc[df[df['treatment'] in treatments ].index, 'new_col'] = results
```

(The new_col column must be created in advance)

Comment: You can include a condition 'df['treatment'].isin(treatments)' in your lambda function
lambda x: x[y_test] == x[test_prediction] if x[treatment] in treatments else ''

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got such error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects, and I guess it's because the lambda will work for all of the rows on data set, but the predictions from the other hand are only for one fold!

Comment: Can you tell me if the data types in the selected series are the same? Or provide an example of a DataFrame?

Comment: same type, y_test has 0,1 values, so the predictions. I tried updating the lambda btw, but it didn't help: lambda x: x[y_test] == x[test_predictions] if x['treatment'] in treatments else pd.NA,

Comment: I think the types may differ. Try comparing str(x[y_test])==str(x[test_prediction]). Or force to set the types df[y_test].astype(int)

Comment: You are right, passed the error, but when looking at the final result, not all the rows has values, there are many gaps between serieses of True/False

Comment: Theoretically, the spaces will be where the values fall into the treatments. If this is the case, and this is not the result - perhaps I do not understand what you expect. Can you tell me more?

Comment: sure, appreciate your help, my k-fold CV in each iteration trains a classifier with k-1 folds and test it with 1 fold, I make sure that in each iteration I pick a different fold for testing... my goal is that after K iterations of cross validation to have new column that check if the prediction that was given is equal to the y labeled data or not (True/False)... assuming that am covering the whole data set (by selecting different fold each time for testing), then by the end of the process I'll have that new column populated with True if the prediction met the real label and False if not.

Comment: Counting on 'treatment' column to identify that part that was randomized in the test fold in each iteration.

Comment: Okay, tell me, what is Series df['treatment'] responsible for? Do I understand correctly that if the data of this Series does not fall into test_fold['treatment'], then these lines can be simply deleted? Now the empty cells should remain where the rows did not get into the test part, and this should be true.

Comment: No, I need to keep them anyway, but K folds should cover the whole data sets, hence all rows by the end will have their predictions. Just to mention that 'treatment' is not unique, many rows can have the same treatment, but it's guaranteed that one treatment will be always in one fold (and not splitted between more than one)

Comment: I think I understand you. Can try: lambda x: str(x[y_test]) == str(x[tests_predictions]) if x['treatment'] in treatment (remove else). In this case, the values of past iterations should not change.

Comment: I got Invalid syntax in that case, instead I tried: `lambda x: str(x[y_test]) == str(x[test_predictions]) and x['treatment'] in treatments,` now all the rows are populated but with False all the time!

Comment: In this case, you have combined all the conditions into one construction. My option might not be suitable due to the lack of else. Then you can do this: lambda x: str(x[y_test]) == str(x[tests_predictions]) if x['treatment'] in treatment else x

Comment: got ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 97, placement implies 1. I don't understand what is `x[y_test]` and `x[test_predictions]`, y_test & test_predictions are lists and not column names! x is df columns (axis=1), within that principle I used x['treatment']... am I missing something?

Comment: I tried (based on my understanding): `lambda x: x[y_label] == test_predictions if x['treatment'] in treatments else x` and then I got: "ValueError: array length 556 does not match index length 98". that is my initial problem, that I don't have all the values for all the data set, I have it only for one fold in one iteration, and aiming to fill them all by the end of all iterations. hope I managed to explain myself.

Comment: Now, I hope I've learned all the nuances)). I corrected the answer, try it, it should help (The report has been corrected)

Comment: getting: if tolerance is not None:  KeyError: 0 !
I'm trying similar approaches of updating the same final list on going in each iteration, and by the end of all iterations simply to do: `df[y_label + '_pred_' + mode] = predections`